# localize windows phone app titles using Visual Studio Express 2012

Tags: windows-phone-7, localization, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I'd like to localize my app Titles (on windows Phone 7.1), so I've followed this documentation which explains how to create the dll and mui files with Visual Studio Express :

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff967550(v=vs.105).aspx#WP_CreatingLanguageResourceStringsforYourApp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff967550%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#WP_CreatingLanguageResourceStringsforYourApp)

I've downloaded the language-neutral resource project  but unfortunately I get this error  on build :

error RC1015: cannot open include file 'afxres.h'

It seems to be an issue with Visual Studio Express

As mentioned on a few forums, I tried to replace #include "afxres.h"   with   #include "windows.h"   but this doesn't work. (error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'gdi32.lib')

Is there something I missed to make this project work ?

Is there any other way to localize my app titles ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use WP7App Res Lib Generator, it makes the hard work for you http://engine-designs.com/wp7-appreslib-dll-generator.html

Answer (score 0):

1. Replace the ‘include “afxres.h”‘ by ‘include “winnt.rh”‘.
2. Delete all included libraries in Project tab, Properties > Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies.